# Force remount when value changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mount

I have a dropdown list that contains some cart items from a shop. I want the dropdown to re-render every time a cart item is added, but it doesn't and only shows my new cart addition when I close and open the cart again (remounts).

```
const CartDropdown = () => {
    const {setCartProducts, cartProducts} = useContext(CartContext)
    const {setProducts, currentProducts} = useContext(ProductsContext)
    // useEffect(() => {}, [cartProducts])
    const cleanCart = () => {
        const cleanProducts = currentProducts
        console.log(cleanProducts)
        for (let i in cleanProducts) {
            if (cleanProducts[i].hasOwnProperty('quantity')){
                cleanProducts[i].quantity = 0
            }
        }
        setProducts(cleanProducts)
        setCartProducts([])
    }
    return(
        <div className='cart-dropdown-container'>
            <div className='cart-items' forceRemount={force}>
                {cartProducts.map((product) => (
                    <div>
                        <img src={product.imageUrl}></img>
                    </div>)
                )}

            </div>
            <button onClick={cleanCart}>LIMPAR</button>
            <Button children={'FINALIZE PURCHASE'}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I want the `CartDropdown` to remount when the `cartProducts` changes.

Comment: What does your CartContext look like? Also, you need to use a [`key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) when you are mapping over data.

Comment: CartContext = cartProducts (array of objects) and setCartProducts

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what those setters and getters on your `useContext` are returning.

Assuming they are from a `useState()`, then you have to make sure you always pass a different object to the setters.

From [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update):

> ### Bailing out of a state update
>
> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state,
> React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects.
> (React uses the `Object.is` comparison algorithm.)

In other words, simply mutating `currentProducts` and calling `setProducts` passing the same (but now mutated) object will not trigger a reprender.

So your code

```
const cleanProducts = currentProducts
console.log(cleanProducts)
// Mutating cleanProducts
setProducts(cleanProducts)
```

Should be something like

```
const cleanProducts = [...currentProducts] // <--- changed this line 
console.log(cleanProducts)
// Mutating cleanProducts
setProducts(cleanProducts)
```

And you have to do this everywhere you call setters.

Another thing, you should add a `key` attribute to elements used in a `.map()`. For instance:

```
{cartProducts.map((product) => (
    <div key={product.imageUrl}>
        <img src={product.imageUrl}></img>
    </div>)
)}
```

Comment: the clearCart func works well... all i want is CartDropdown to fully remount everytime cartProducts changes

Comment: What's the code in `useContext`?